# Menu lift up when use tab key in google chrome and IE

Tags: css

I have made the menu with CSS {overflow:hidden} and use JQUERY to lift up menu when hover on it. But there is one issue occur in google chrome browser. When I press tab key from keyboard to select menu, all the menus are lifted up and showed. If I not use {overflow:hidden} in menu CSS, then can select menu with tab key and design is OK. So kindly advise me how should I handle for this case? Thank You.

Comment: When pressing tab gives :focus to the <input>, the browser scrolls the focused element into view. This is from a Chromium point of view. Maybe try to give the elements a position: fixed instead of absolute. However, you  could create css conditions only for :focus but it could get dirty.